# Different results from Postgres EXPLAIN ANALYZE

Tags: postgresql, explain

I was investigating the performance of a query that hit the top of my list in PMM and noticed strange behavior. The first time the requests execution time is long, subsequent times quickly:

```
Aggregate  (cost=1026.84..1026.85 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=17.657..17.659 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.12..1026.80 rows=15 width=37) (actual time=0.844..17.625 rows=24 loops=1)
        ->  Index Scan using i01_recipients on recipients recipiente1_  (cost=0.56..32.94 rows=28 width=37) (actual time=0.129..0.994 rows=24 loops=1)
              Index Cond: ((user_reference)::text = 'b8245f69-f429-4bc3-80c3-78de75ffb7b8'::text)
        ->  Index Scan using i01_messages on messages messageent0_  (cost=0.56..35.37 rows=12 width=74) (actual time=0.638..0.688 rows=1 loops=24)
              Index Cond: ((recipient_id)::text = (recipiente1_.id)::text)
              Filter: (((channel)::text = 'INTERNAL'::text) AND ((status)::text = ANY ('{SENT,DELIVERED,READ}'::text[])))
              Rows Removed by Filter: 1
Planning Time: 0.639 ms
Execution Time: 17.713 ms


Aggregate  (cost=1026.84..1026.85 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.790..0.792 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.12..1026.80 rows=15 width=37) (actual time=0.092..0.779 rows=24 loops=1)
        ->  Index Scan using i01_recipients on recipients recipiente1_  (cost=0.56..32.94 rows=28 width=37) (actual time=0.031..0.078 rows=24 loops=1)
              Index Cond: ((user_reference)::text = 'b8245f69-f429-4bc3-80c3-78de75ffb7b8'::text)
        ->  Index Scan using i01_messages on messages messageent0_  (cost=0.56..35.37 rows=12 width=74) (actual time=0.026..0.027 rows=1 loops=24)
              Index Cond: ((recipient_id)::text = (recipiente1_.id)::text)
              Filter: (((channel)::text = 'INTERNAL'::text) AND ((status)::text = ANY ('{SENT,DELIVERED,READ}'::text[])))
              Rows Removed by Filter: 1
Planning Time: 0.505 ms
Execution Time: 0.839 ms
```

I'm not a big postgres expert. Could you explain to me why this is happening and why this request is loading my system.

Comment: Caching. If you run `explain (analyze, buffers)` you will see how many blocks had to be retrieved from disk and how many were in the buffer cache

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by **a_horse_with_no_name** in his comment, this is in general a standard behaviour of the most prevalent DBMS (Database Management Systems)

When a database instance is started or when a server is rebooted, the memory will contain no data from the databases.

During the first run of a query the DBMS system will request the relevant data from disk and store the (column-, table-) data in memory. It will then read the data from memory and according to the statement present the data to the (client) request.

1. Read request / query
2. Determine table(s) to retrieve data from disk (normally in pages)
3. Store retrieved data (pages) in memory
4. Perform JOINS
5. Apply Predicates
6. Return data to client

Subsequent queries requiring the same data will do all of the above, but without having to read the data from disk (Step 2.), which is quite resource intensive and slow. Generally (depending on your postgresql.conf settings) the data (pages) will almost surely be still in RAM/memory for subsequent queries.

This is why most DBMS perform better with more RAM.

#### Reference Reading

- [18.1 Setting Parameter](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/config-setting.html) (PostgreSQL | Docs : postgresql.conf Basics)
- [Resource Consumption](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/runtime-config-resource.html) (PostgreSQL | Docs : General PostgreSQL Memory Settings)
- [F.27. pg_buffercache](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/pgbuffercache.html) (PostgreSQL | Docs : See what's in the buffer cache)
- [EXPLAIN](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/sql-explain.html) (PostgreSQL | Docs : EXPLAIN command)